# Change contact name display

Tags: community, page-layout

I would like to change the contact name that shows on the top of the contact page.  The spot where the picture shows as well as the links to linked in, twitter, facebook, etc...  It is above the 'Contact Detail' line.  Any thoughts on how to change it?  It doesn't appear to be available for change in the standard page layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I submitted a ticket with Salesforce and found that there is an item in IdeaExchange to allow this functionality.  For anyone else who is interested in this functionality, visit the following link and vote for this idea:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqVVAA0

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the record landing page by creating a Visualforce page and overriding the tab action of the Contact record in **Setup > Customize > Contacts > Buttons Field and Actions**.

This is an extreme step, however, and you will be required to rebuild much of that tab UI. It is probably much more extreme than you'll want to commit to given all you want is to change the formatting of the contact name.

The good news is that much of this can be grabbed from the coarse metadata components like apex:listViews or apex:enhancedList. But some of it might not be easy to recreate.

Comment: That does sound extreme.  I will need to revisit this request.